# Transitioning from height: 0 to height:auto, and back again using JavaScript and VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm transitioning from height 0px to height auto (because I'm not sure how big in height the container will ultimately need to be, max-height COULD be an alternative, but I'd prefer to do it this way instead.

transitioning from 0 to auto seems to work just fine, however transitioning from auto back to 0 doesn't execute at the desired animation duration as height 0 to auto (collapse to expand).

https://codesandbox.io/s/q3471wj81w

Comment: It's working fine for me. I checked in the `computed` section of Chrome's debugger and your height property is being set to 0 when the div is collapsed. I'm not seeing your problem.

Comment: Correct it's collapsing, however the transition: height 250ms ease does not seem to be firing for the collapse (it fires for the expand) at least on my browser (chrome). the transition between expanded and collapse is instant, and the from collapse to expanded the transition happens over 250ms ease.

Comment: Then to start with you need to change this: "however transitioning from auto back to 0 doesn't execute the transition at all." because it is working. Just not at the rate you want it to work.

Comment: How do you want the article body to be by default? Showing or not showing?

Comment: It still works fine for me. The opening if the chevron is gradual and the collapse is instantenous. Here are some print statements I wrote into your code and allowed to print while the code was running:

false
height 0px 
height2 0px 
true
height 216px 
height2 216px 
inside timeout 
false
height 0px 
height2 0px 
true
height 216px 
height2 216px 
inside timeout

Comment: The default state would be showing

Comment: Again, this is what I have observed. Based on what you're saying your code is working on my machine.

Comment: Transition from 0 to auto doesn't work too. It works in your example because you shift from 0 to specified height. To make it work in closing, you need to set a specified height first and then set height = 0 in a next tick to start a transition.

Answer (score 0):

animate the `max-height` instead, set the height to `auto` and `max-height` to a bigger value than you will have and set the transition on `max-height` and set it to `0` when collapsing, `overflow:hidden` will hide the text when collapsing.

i couldn't get it to work on your `VueJs` but here's an example of how that works, tweak it to your needs :

```js
let article = document.querySelector('p');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  article.classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

```css
p {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  transition: max-height .3s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #aaa;
}

.collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
collapse
</button>
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque at magna ac tellus volutpat cursus sed vitae nisi. Ut pellentesque mauris et orci sagittis placerat. Vivamus a dui sem. Morbi dignissim dictum elit sodales feugiat. Fusce in dolor
    non erat pretium malesuada ac at odio. Nulla consectetur, est et conseqc fringilla ligula egenisi ornare odio, vitae sodales ante ex non mauris. Vivamus iaculis faucibus nibh, nec posuere sapien posuere eget. Nulla ac est est. Nulla interdum vel eros
    vitae lobortis.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the transition will take shorter time when it's not the same amount of content, also, if you are making a component to a customer this solution won't work as you never know how much content is gone fit in that.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a way to solve this. Transition to and from auto is the issue, so I did a little refactoring.

I set height from auto back to px using the scrollHeight as the basis, and then set the height to 0 using a timeout which gives the transition enough time to kick in.

https://codesandbox.io/s/oxj8rm3oyy

Comment: Yeah the same approach I took. Completely valid. Did almost the same but a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

A way of solving it is updating your `startTransition` method in your `Article` component like so:

```
startTransition(evt) {
  const _height = this.$refs.articleBody.scrollHeight;
  this.height =  this.show ? `${_height}px` : 0;
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.height =  !this.show ? `${_height}px` : 0;
      this.show = !this.show;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
  }, 50);
}
```

It can be refactor a little but it gets the job done. It gives you time to set up the height in the initial state and then triggers the height change.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for hijacking this old thread. But if anyone else is scratching their head with this like I did, I would have been hppy to find an updated answer. This is quite easy using directives in vue. You could then also animate height changes. All without using any weird moving of elements outside of dom or guessing a max-height.